# addEventListener in JS does not work properly

Tags: javascript, media-queries, addeventlistener

I am making a Web Site in which I want to shrink the navigation bar on the first scroll, but I want that to happen only on desktop.

I am using a `mediaQuery.addEventListener` to look for change in the viewport size, but when I shrink the width of the page, it still shrinks the nav-bar, it stops that only when I refresh the page, and when I resize the window back to full width, it shrinks itself again as it should, but without the need to refresh.

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)")
handleDeviceChange(mediaQuery);
mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleDeviceChange);
function handleDeviceChange(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        //code that shrinks nav-bar on first scroll
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you want answers, [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and check : Help others reproduce the problem

Comment: May want to read this article on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#monitoring_screen_resolution_or_zoom_level_changes

Comment: Perhaps you could check some logic. I don't understand the "i want to happen only on desktop" and your media query min-width 992px. Min-width 992px means min-width 992px not desktop or mobile! Easier way, I would define the nav-bar shrink, and if min-width 992px (to stay with value you are giving) just change the property you're using in your nav-bar to shrink it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add resize listener to visualViwport to detect viewport width on change. here is how:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var vp = visualViewport;

vp.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    if (vp.width <= 400) {

       // console.log(vp.width);
        nav.style.background = "red";
        nav.style.height = "100px";
    }
    else {

        nav.style.background = "lightcoral";
        nav.style.height = "150px";
    }
});
```

```css
#nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: lightcoral;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">nav</nav>
```

Comment: @Anoxious please replace your question title with this: ` How can I adjust the nav bar according to viewport width without using CSS media query?`